# Where to find username and password in MongoDB for completion of connection string Mongoose => MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, connection-string

I am trying to finish up with my connection string that is required to establish connection between Mongoose and MongoDB the required parameters for the connection string require the username and password, In general I suppose I have the password as that's what I am logging-in with but where can I find my MongoDB username, It's showing me that its same as my Gmail account but seems that inputting these values in my connection string is throwing out an error :

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous>
```

Hence, I suppose my username is not what MongoDB is saying that its my Gmail so where and how can I find my username

MongoDB image : [image]

also can someone pls say me what should I replace myFirstDatabaes value with in the connection string,
Thanks for reviewing my post and helping me out

EDIT : Also, I suppose because of the error and incorrect details my page is stuck loading and isn't refreshing to the new content while sending example data to MongoDB

Comment: That is you account login for the mongodb cloud. If you go to overview, then "visit Mongodb Atlas", you can create / view your databases. Each database has it's own username/password which can be set & viewed there

Comment: k did that and from can i get the name of the DB sry for silly qs and for the inconvenience caused, ty and i suppose i had to add a database user and use those credentials